# Java make a thread update a variable

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to have a thread which will update a variable in other class.

Say, I have an integer, and a thread class which has a Socket that gets a value, and I want that value to be set to my integer.

I have en ENUM called direction , which has the values UP,DOWN
I have a main class which has a direction variable 
In that main class I'm starting a thread which has a socket in it
the thread looks like:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    DataInputStream in;
    volatile direction dir;
    public Server(int port,direction d) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
        in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        dir=d;
    }
    public void run() {
        int recieved;
        while (true) {
            try {
                recieved = in.readInt();
                while (recieved != -1) {
                    dir = direction.fromInt(recieved);
                    recieved = in.readInt();
                    System.out.println(dir);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public direction getDirection() {
        return dir;
    }

}
```

I want the direction variable in the main class to update from the thread class

Comment: What have you tried? What did not work? What does the code of the class holding the integer look like? etc. In other words: you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
Socket socket = new Socket("myhost", myport);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
// read your value
int val = dis.readInt();
myClass.setValue(val);
```

In your class, use a volatile integer.

```
private volatile int value;

public void setValue(int val)
{
    value = val;
}
```

Make sure the thread has a pointer to your class instance. Do this using the constructor, for example.

Comment: That is not important. Just try something, based on what I wrote here. Just make sure that the Thread has a pointer to your class.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you posted, you don't need to do anything really, just read the variable (because it is volatile in Server):

```
Server server = new Server(...);
server.start();

//when you need it:

Direction dir = server.getDirection();
```

---

Now if your question is: can I have main get the various values of `dir` as they come to the Server object, you could use a `BlockingQueue` for example to handle the communication. In your Server class, declare the queue (and remove the `dir` member):

```
private BlockingQueue<Direction> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Direction> ();
```

Then in your run method:

```
Direction dir = Direction.fromInt(recieved);
queue.put(dir);
```

and your `getDirection` method could be renamed `getNextDirection`:

```
public Direction getNextDirection() throws InterruptedException {
    queue.take();
}
```

Your main could then look like this:

```
while (true) {
    Direction nextDirection = server.getNextDirection()
    //do something with the new direction
}
```

Note: I have renamed your enum `Direction` instead of `direction` to respect Java Naming Conventions.

Comment: I tried to connect the socket to port 80 for some reason...But when I changed the port, it worked! thanks!